# Overloading operators << and >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In a code a professor of mine developed, there's a class called `Node`. In that class, operators `<<` and `>>` are overloaded as follows:

```
// Overloaded write operator
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& obj);
// Overloaded input operator
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Node& obj);
```

Does anyone know:

- The meaning of `const` in the first signature, and why is not possible to use `const` in the second one?
- The purpose of `&` after `Node` in the second signature.

Comment: `const`, as the word itself implies, means the referenced object is un-modifiable. Since `opaerator>>` needs to modify `obj`...

Comment: Aren't these the questions that You were supposed to figure out and answer on your own? They kinda seems so.

Comment: This is covered by any introductory text on C++. SO is not a replacement for one.

Comment: Your best bet for C++ syntax basics like this would be to study a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465)

Answer (score 1):

`const Node& obj` means that the argument `obj` is a reference to a constant `Node` object.

`Node& obj` means that the argument `obj` is a reference to a mutable (non-constant) `Node` object.

The logic here is, that when you read write something to a stream, you don't need to modify that something, hence it can be `const`. But when you read something from a stream and write it to some object, that object can not be `const`.

Comment: It's worth noting what this leads to (i.e. you can output both const- and non-const nodes, but you can input only info a non-const node)

Answer (score 1):

- `&` Pass by reference. The argument passed in is the same as the object caller passing. No copy is occurred. It is needed if you need mutate some variable in function.
- `const` Read-only. Any modification on this object causes compile error. It is  a useful restrict to let compiler help you not accidentally modify it.

object to `<<ostream` is to read the passing argument to output to `ostream`. So it make sense to mark it as `const`. Marking `&` to avoid unnecessary copy.

`istream>>` to your obj. Read from istream to write your obj. So you must pass it as non-const reference to update some values on your passing object.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way: const means that obj can't be changed.

The first function is overload of output operator. It only read the data of obj and writes it to output stream in some form.

The second function is overload of input operator. It reads from input stream into obj. Which means it alters obj. Therefore obj can't be marked const!